# Can I use html in the chrome.windows.update function

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Can I use html code in the window created by chrome.windows.create function in javascript by updating it with the chrome.windows.update and add the html from a variable in javascript

Comment: I can't understand your question. Could you please explain more detail what you are trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to open an chrome.windows panel and insert html into it from a Javascript variable

Answer (score 0):

A "window", in Chrome parlance, is a container for tabs. Tabs contain HTML documents, and you can manipulate those documents using methods like [`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript). Windows do not directly contain any HTML content, though, so: no, there is no way to pass HTML to `chrome.windows.create` (or `.update`), as a window has no use for HTML.